# Latex table moves out of section and into the next page

Tags: latex

I am making a journal paper with 2 columns. But I need table for the entire column. Using the below code table is pushed out of the comparatively analysis section into a new page.

```
\section{Comparatively Analysis}
\hfil\break
\begin{table*}
\centerline {TABLE 1} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|c|} 

\hline
\multicolumn{5} { | c | }{Comparison Table}\\
\hline
Paper & Dataset & Approach & Model & Evaluation \\
\hline
Mary[7] & Air Pollution & Statistical & ST Correlation & RMSE 3.54 for 15\% missing data\\
\hline
Zhang[10] & Water Quality & Deep Learning & Seq2Seq & RMSE 3.29 \\
\hline
Turabieh[11] & Mammographic Mass, Hepatitis & Soft Computing & ANFIS-GA,ANFIS-PSO& Accuracy 85.2\% \\
\hline
Verma[12] & MIT-BIH ECG & Deep Learning & LSTM & 5-step RMSE 0.1 and 10-step RMSE 0.07 \\
\hline
Al-Milli[13] & Mammographic Mass & Deep Learning & Jordan RNN & Accuracy 84.27\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\hfil\break


\section{Conclusion}
Due to improper internet communications
```

[TABLE OUT OF SECTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTiuc.png)

[NEW PAGE TABLE PUSHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWCi.png)

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the table is too large. You have to use `resizebox` method from `graphicx` package. Here I provide a slightly better-looking table from the `tabu` package; this format is widely used in academia and in textbooks.

```
\usepackage{tabu, makecell, graphicx, booktabs}
%%Begin document (...)

\section{Comparatively}
\hfil\break
\begin{center}
\tabulinesep=1.6mm          %%height between lines
\resizebox{1.1\columnwidth}{!}{    %% 1.1 is the scale factor of the column width
    \begin{tabu}{ccccc}
        \toprule
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\ \ \ Comparison Table}\\
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Paper}}&\multicolumn{1}{c} 
        {\textit{Dataset}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Approach}}&\multicolumn{1}{c} 
        {Model}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{ Evaluation}}\\
        \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} 
        \cmidrule(lr){5-5}

           Mary$[7]$ & Air Pollution                              & Statistical    & ST Correlation                     & \makecell{RMSE $3.54$ for \\ $15\%$ missing data }  \\
        Zhang$[10]$  & Water Quality                              & Deep Learning  & Seq$2$Seq                          & RMSE $3.29$                                         \\
      Turabieh$[11]$ &  \makecell{Mammographic mass \\ Hepatitis} & Soft Computing & \makecell{ANFIS-GA,\\ ANGIS-PSO}   & Accuracy $85.2\%$                                    \\
        \bottomrule
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
}
\end{center} 
{ \footnotesize\textbf{Table 1:} Table description } 
\hfil\break

\section{Conclusion}
Due to improper internet communications
```

[image]

Change the `scale factor back to 1.0 if the table seems to overlap to much on the right side. If not keep it at 1.1 for better visibility.

Comment: Thanks and how can I have all sides borders in your solution table